# react authentication flow verification

Tags: node.js, authentication, reactjs, token, jwt

I have some API in nodejs and a React App for client side. I try to create the auth system for my API/backoffice with a jwt token, I use `jsonwebtoken` for create and verify token on server side but I have some doubt for client side...now on login I save the token on localstorage, then with React-Router "onUpdate" I check if local storage has a token, if not I redirect to login else nothing append, then on my app I append an auth header for each ajax request.

This is my router

```
export const isLoggedIn = (nextState, replace) => {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
}
<Router history={browserHistory} onUpdate={isLoggedIn} >
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Login.Login} />
        <Route path="admin/" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="admin/tutti" component={Users} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Here I login

```
$.get('/login',credential, function (result) {
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', result.token)
});
```

Generic request:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/api/users",
    type:'GET',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success:function (result) {},
    headers: {"x-access-token": localStorage.getItem('id_token')}
});
```

is this a correct way to manage the React auth flow?
my doubt is, on isLoggedIn I need to verify the token in some way?

thank you at all!

Answer (score 1):

Do you know `Higher Order Components`?

Here is an article about HOC: https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.hb4ck2u52

React authentication flow can be written as a HOC.

For example:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default function (ComposedComponent) {
  class Auth extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
      const isLoggedIn = .... // your way to check if current user is logged in
      if (!isLoggedIn) {
        browserHistory.push('/'); // if not logged in, redirect to your login page
      }
    }
    render() {
      return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
  return Auth;
}
```

But I suggest you to use FLUX flow, such as Redux, and store your state in Redux store.

Here is my Redux implementation:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

export default function (ComposedComponent) {
  class Auth extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
      if (!this.props.isLoggedIn) {
        browserHistory.push('/login');
      }
    }
    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
      if (!nextProps.isLoggedIn) {
        browserHistory.push('/login');
      }
    }
    render() {
      return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
  Auth.propTypes = {
    isLoggedIn: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  };
  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { isLoggedIn: state.userReducer.isLoggedIn };
  }
  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Auth);
}
```

Usage:

```
import auth from '/path/to/HOC/Auth';

<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Login.Login} />
        <Route path="admin/" component={auth(Dashboard)} /> // wrap components supported to be protected
        <Route path="admin/tutti" component={auth(Users)} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: thank you for this answer, I study this way, but I have a question, on mount/update it is useless verify every time the token?